# GAMS - Unit step function

Tags: gams-math

I need to use the **step function** in order to count the number of non-zero elements in a parameter. The step function that I am considering is the following:

[image: f(x)={0 if x = 0 else 1}]
[image: Plot of step function (where f(0)=0)]

After searching on the internet for solution, I realized we can create **stepwise functions** in GAMS, but I need a continuous function for x > 1.
I tried the following code to reproduce a step-like function:

```
round(1 / (1 + exp(-x)) - 0.01)
```

which is:

[image: step-like function]
[image]

Unfortunately, this formula does not work with GAMS. When I try to run the code, I got this error:

```
Endogenous function argument(s) not allowed in linear models
```

I am working with a **MIP** (**M**ixed **I**nteger Linear **P**rogram) model. Is there a way to use a step function in GAMS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume, that x is a variable in your code? Then you can try something like this (if x would be a parameter, it would be easier):

```
Equation        a, b;
Variable        x;
Binary Variable y;

Scalar BigM   / 1e3/
       SmallM /1e-3/;

a.. y*BigM   =g= x;
b.. y*SmallM =l= x;
```

So, if x=0, y will be 0 as well because of equation b. And if x>0, y will become 1 because of equation a. The BigM you should choose as small as possible and as big as necessary (so it should be the maximum value x can take) and SmallM the other way around. This assumes of course, that there is something like a lower and upper bound for x, if it is not 0...

Hope that helps!

Lutz